# How to find values represented as NA in a data frame using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

For example, I want to subset or condition all the values represented as NA in a dataset called "data" in the column of "x". How to do it?
I have tried the following code, but it gave me 0 observations.

```
NA1 <- subset(data, data$x==NA)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `is.na(data$x)` instead.

Comment: you don't need to reference `data` in `subset` so `subset(data, x==NA)`. also, `NA` is a non-comparable, so you need a special function `subset(data, is.na(x))` but this gives you a data frame. I'm not sure if you want that or a vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.table` package can be a very convenient tool to work with datasets. Especially if the data you are working is large.

Suppose you have a data table with two variables and one of them have `NA` values

```
> DT = data.table(var1=c(1,NA,3,NA), var2=c(5,6,7,8))
> DT
   var1 var2
1:    1    5
2:   NA    6
3:    3    7
4:   NA    8
```

Then you can simply use `which()` command to find the subset of `NAs` or apply 'not' operator in front `!which()` to subset those rows that don't have `NAs` in var1.

```
> DT[which(is.na(var1))]
   var1 var2
1:   NA    6
2:   NA    8
```

Point out that the statement above will only print the result and will not make any changes to the original data table.

[Here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf) you can find a great FAQ on `data.table`.

Comment: Pointing to the [new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) might be more helpful.